# Won't render animation after having already rendered a version

Tags: rendering, animation, blender-internal-render-engine

I'm very new to blender and not a very techy person. I rendered out a simple animation of a logo as a sequence of png files, then edited it in the video sequence editor. I was able to do this with no problems.

Next, I made edits to the original blender file of the logo, adding text and lights, and creating different camera moves. This time, when I tried to render out the png sequence, nothing happens. I tried to trouble shoot using questions people have asked in the past, but I still have no luck. 
Can anyone help? Thanks.[image: my render settings for the new animation]

Comment: When you says "Nothing happened" what happened? Was there any error message, did the Animation button depress. Can you set the output folder to a different location and check for new files. Everything in your screen shot looks reasonable. Could you share the .blend file here? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=17GI2bTVj62RtFm_6L1hl4m5PYJdnaA8d

Comment: Thanks for your help! ^That link should take you to the blender file. When I say nothing happens, I mean the program literally does nothing. I think it loads the sequence editor for like a second, but that's all the activity I see happening.

Comment: You know what, I just realized, it's rendering out the original sequence I created, and not adjusting for the edits I made to the file. Does that make sense? Do you know how I can get it to render the new version I created?

Answer (score 0):

You have added an image file to the VSE (Video Sequence Editor) and as you have not added your scene to the VSE, all Blender tries to do is output that one file for each frame.

You can either delete the **Image strip** from the VSE or disable the **Sequencer** under **Post Processing** in the Render settings.

Comment: Please mark as Answer so others can benefit and, your welcome.